# What does this function definition mean? involving an input matrix and a scalar

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

Please explain the meaning of the function definition. A function takes two inputs: a matrix N and a scalar n, in that order, where each dimension of N is greater than or equal to n. The function returns the n-by-n square array at the bottom left corner of N.

so i have tried this but getting an error from the solver

```
function N = bottom_left(N,n)

    N(end-n+1:end,1:n)= n

end
```

Comment: is this code you have written yourself? your trying to make a function called bottom left?

Comment: yes i have written it myself, the function name is bottom_left

Comment: Did you test the function yourself? Generate a (random) (5x7) matrix and print the matrix and the output for n=3.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes two inputs `N` and `n`.

`N` represents the dimensions of the matrix. while `n` represents a scalar value that is equal or smaller than the dimension of `N`.

The output of the function will produce a square matrix with dimensions `n` which is made up of the values in matrix `N`from its lower left corner. the size of the new matrix will have the dimensions `n`.

If `N` and `n` are equal the resultant matrix will be the same as `N`.

[image: diagram]

Comment: the following what? you don't understand my explanation?

Comment: i m trying this but its not working                                                                                     >>function N = bottom_left(N,n)
>>N(end-n+1:end,1:n)= n
>>end

Comment: can you post the code for the function in the question (use the edit button) and show what you are trying.. it will make it easier to understand the problem and others will be able to benefit more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
function bottom_left
g = input(' Enter the number of rows : ');
h = input(' Enter the number of columns : ');
n = input(' Enter the dimension n of the square array you want to have : ');

fprintf('A square matrix of the dimensions you enyered is \n')
A = rand(n,n)

if g < n  ||  h < n
    fprintf(' Please note that dimensions of the matrix must be greater than the number you entered! \n ');
else 
    N = randi(100,g,h)
    N(g-n+1:end,1:n) = A

end
```

Hope this helps!